# MassTransit - Exception during receive message in MassTransit.ReceiveTransport

Tags: masstransit

I get the following weird error when mt tries to receive message from queue.

Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

```
at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(Boolean overflow, String failureMessageID)
at System.Guid.TryParseExactD(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(ReadOnlySpan`1 guidString, GuidResult& result)
at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
at System.ComponentModel.GuidConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.TryConvertValue(Type type, String value, String path, Object& result, Exception& error)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.Util.TaskUtil.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<DisposeAsync>g__Faulted|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConcurrencyLimit.ConsumeConcurrencyLimitFilter`1.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

My consumer is not executed and the message goes to _error queue.
We use MassTransit 7.3.0

I don't change anything, the same code works fine on another server (uat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.TryConvertValue(Type type, String value, String path, Object& result, Exception& error)
```

Clearly, something in your configuration is expecting a `Guid` value, and it isn't a *Guid*. The fact this it is happening when trying to resolve a consumer from the container doesn't appear to be the root cause.

Comment: Thank you, I don't exactly understand what configuration you mention. Consumer registered (as other consumers in app) in DI (AddScoped) and connected to endpoint in ReceiveEndpoint delegate. As I sad, other consumers in that endpoint (and other endpoints) works properly.

Comment: Look at the dependencies of the failing consumer.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were right, it was dependent service problem.